# Shared Hosting Compilation

Tags: compilation, asp.net-4.0

It seems that whenever I upload a file onto my shared hosting site, the site goes offline whilst it compiles the page no matter how slight the change is.  It seems its compiling the whole site.  I have something like 5000+ pages on my site. My question is :-

Is this normal on a shared hosting site?

Is there something I missed or have left out of the web.config that will force the compiler to only compile as and when the page is accessed rather than compile the whole site which it seems to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, IIS recompiles everything into assemblies, so a small change might affect the whole site.  Because of this, the whole site is recompiled.  It's recommended to do deployments like this during off-peak hours due to the delay.

One thing you can do is to precompile the site before deploying it to the server.  You can find this option when publishing the site in visual studio (right click on the project node in Solution Explorer and choose publish.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought.  No wonder why PHP wins at 50%.